# Есть ли возможность использовать Filtered Stream Twitter бесплатно или с минимальными затратами?

Tags: потоки-данных, twitter, twitter-api

писал свое приложение для пересылки твитов с твитера в телеграм, использовал для этого Filtered Stream, однако в один момент этот метод убрался с бесплатных тарифов и теперь только в Pro (5к$ в месяц) и Enterprise (от 42к$ в месяц). Понятное дело, что таких сумм у меня для мелкого, некоммерческого проекта для себя, нет. Поэтому возник вопрос, можно ли еще как-то получать твиты от определенных людей как можно было в Filtered Stream за минимальную оплату или в идеале бесплатно.